# Import python module from a package in src dir by installing project in its environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

For my Python project I work with VSCode and conda environment. My project structure is similar to this:

```
my_project
├── setup.py
├── data
└── src
    └── pkg
        ├── module
        │   ├── file.py
        │   └── __init__.py
        └── main.py
```

I installed this as a package in another_project environment. When I import a module this works fine with:

```
from pkg.module.module import some_class
```

But when I run the main.py in my_project the same import raises

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'pkg'
```

It works when I change the import to

```
from src.pkg.module.module import some_class
```

How can I get the import running in my_project without the `src.` in front of the import?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to install the project for itself. This adds an `my_project/build/lib/pkg` folder (with simlink representation of the pkg) and a `my_project/src/pkg.egg-info`.

This is working for me, but runs into problems when sharing the repo with other. They need to install the project in their environments as well. To do so, from inside the my_project dir run `pip install -e .`

Make sure to have a `setup.py` in your project including

```
setuptools.setup(
    name="project",
    packages=setuptools.find_namespace_packages(where='src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
)
```

Comment: This also makes testing with pytest easier!